# Pipelined MIPS delayed branching example

Tags: assembly, mips, pipeline

I'm given this MIPS pseudo-assembly code:

```
    add r7,r8,r9
    beq r1,r2,40 ---
    lw r4,O(r1)    '
    sub r5,r1,r4   '
    and r6,r4,r2   '
  <--------------- '
    or r4,r2,r3
```

I am supposed to assume that there are **no structural hazards** and that **delayed branching** is used.

The questions are:

- how will the instructions be executed in case of branching
- is(are) the instruction(s) in the delay slot useful
- will the execution of the instruction in the delay slot generate a wrong result
- what if there was no branching, i.e. the condition for branching wasn't met

I'm preparing for a test, and I don't quite understand this concept of delayed branching. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MIPS has a five-stage pipeline. An effect is that the instruction after a branch will be performed regardless of whether the branch is taken. In simplified terms, compared to traditional assembly languages you need to move the branch up one instruction earlier.

So if the branch is taken then code performed will be:

```
add r7,r8,r9
lw r4,O(r1)
or r4,r2,r3
```

If the branch is not taken then code performed will be:

```
add r7,r8,r9
lw r4,O(r1)
sub r5,r1,r4
and r6,r4,r2
or r4,r2,r3
```

The lack of structural hazards hint essentially means you don't also have to consider other pipeline effects.

Comment: Is it a rule that *only one* instruction after the branch will be performed? Why not all three?

Comment: @Eutherpy yes. The first two stages of the pipeline are (1) instruction fetch; (2) instruction decode. Branch decisions are easy so are made at (2) (unlike normal arithmetic stuff, which occurs at (3)). That always leaves only exactly one instruction already loaded before the proper PC is known and available for the next load at (1).

Answer (score 1):

1. The `lw r4,0(r1)` will be executed before the branch is taken. This is what delayed branching is.
2. No, not if the branch is taken.
3. No, because r4 is overwritten by the `or r4,r2,r3` anyway.
4. All instructions execute in order.

Answer (score 1):

Delayed branching means that the instruction following a branch statement is executed whether the branch is taken or not.

So here are my answers to your questions:

- how will the instructions be executed in case of branching

  The instruction following the branch will be executed, so:

  `add r7,r8,r9`

  `beq r1,r2,40`

  `lw r4,O(r1)   # This instruction is executed even if the branch is taken`

  `or r4,r2,r3`
- is(are)the instruction(s) in the delay slot useful

  In this case, yes if the branch is not taken. If the branch is taken r4 will be overwritten so it would not be useful
- will the execution of the instruction in the delay slot generate a wrong result

  No, because if the branch is taken the instruction `or r4,r2,r3` will overwrite `r4`.

  Note however that the `lw` instruction in the delay slot may issue a trap, in which case you'd get a wrong behavior
- what if there was no branching, i.e. the condition for branching wasn't met

  Then there is no problem, the program continues execution